# Is There is a way in .net to get centroid for polyline?

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin

I want to get the centroid of polyline2d.  I have a polyline from TraceBoundary like so:

```
DBObjectCollection objs = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.TraceBoundary(Point, false);
Polyline polyline = (Polyline)objs[0];
Point2d centroid = ***The missing part i need any way to get center of gravity of the above polyline as point2d***
```

I was doing that before with autolisp:

```
(setq arob (entlast))
(setq enpol (vlax-ename->vla-object arob))
(setq cgpoint (vlax-get-property enpol 'Centroid))
```

I have a mathematical solution, but it's not valid when the polyline comes with some curves.

I won't use this function:

```
public static Point2d GetPolyLineCentroid(Polyline polyline)
    {
        double area = polyline.Area;
        double cx = 0.0;
        double cy = 0.0;
        double X0 = 0.0;
        double Y0 = 0.0;
        double X1 = 0.0;
        double Y1 = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < polyline.NumberOfVertices - 1; i++)
        {
            X0 = polyline.GetPoint2dAt(i).X;
            Y0 = polyline.GetPoint2dAt(i).Y;
            X1 = polyline.GetPoint2dAt(i + 1).X;
            Y1 = polyline.GetPoint2dAt(i + 1).Y;

            cx += (X0 + X1) * (X0 * Y1 - X1 * Y0);
            cy += (Y0 + Y1) * (X0 * Y1 - X1 * Y0);
        }

        // last Point
        int Lv = polyline.NumberOfVertices - 1;
        X0 = polyline.GetPoint2dAt(Lv).X;
        Y0 = polyline.GetPoint2dAt(Lv).Y;
        X1 = polyline.GetPoint2dAt(0).X;
        Y1 = polyline.GetPoint2dAt(0).Y;

        cx += (X0 + X1) * (X0 * Y1 - X1 * Y0);
        cy += (Y0 + Y1) * (X0 * Y1 - X1 * Y0);


        cx /= 6 * area;
        cy /= 6 * area;

        return new Point2d(cx, cy);
    }
```

I don't want to use AutoLisp.  Is there a way to do this in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution and it's valid for me:

```
public static Point2d GetPolyLineCentroid(DBObjectCollection objs)
{
    Solid3d Solid = new Solid3d();
    Solid.Extrude(((Region)Region.CreateFromCurves(objs)[0]), 1, 0);
    Point2d centroid = new Point2d(Solid.MassProperties.Centroid.X, Solid.MassProperties.Centroid.Y);
    Solid.Dispose();
    return centroid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For AutoCAD <= 2013, create a region with .NET (`Region.CreateFromCurves`), and get a reference to it with COM and the `HandleToObject` method. On the region ActiveX object, there is a `Centroid` property.

For AutoCAD > 2013, there is a `AreaProperties` method on the `Region` class that returns a `RegionAreaProperties` structure with a `Centroid` property.

Comment: @Maxence - small world it is - do you know if it's possible to get a reference to the region without using COM?